# Flutter theme does not apply to physical device preview

Tags: android, flutter, mobile-app-testing

I have created and apply custom theme for my flutter app and it correctly previewed in my emulator. But when I check it from my physical device it does not apply any theme effect.

```
 Text('Hello World!' ,style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1),
```

Above code headline1 I have customized like,

```
headline1: GoogleFonts.roboto(
        color: Colors.black38,
        fontSize: 22,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
        height: 1,
      ),
```

In the physical device it use default headline1.

I want to apply my custom theme to physical device as well

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already added internet permission to `AndroidManifest`, then that might be the reason.

Go to `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and add this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

It must be outside the application tag, but inside the manifest tag.

Comment: I tried this one. But the problem as it is

Comment: Try uninstalling and then reinstall